# How can i sum linetotal in blade file out of foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel

i want to sum the mark variable on blade file.
i don't have the line total field on table in database.
i find the sum qty and price in line total, but i want to sum all line total.

```
 <?php
        $sl = 1;
      ?>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($qInvoice as $sInvoice)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$sl++}}</td>
                <td>{{$sInvoice->catName}}</td>
                <td>{{$sInvoice->proName}}</td>
                <td>{{$sInvoice->qty}}</td>
                <td>{{$sInvoice->meName}}</td>
                <td class="text-right">{{$sInvoice->price}}/-</td>
                <td class="text-right">{{$sInvoice->price * $sInvoice->qty}}/-</td>

                <?php
                    $total = 0;
                    $lineTotal = $sInvoice->price * $sInvoice->qty;
                    $total+=$lineTotal;
                ?>

            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"></td>
            <td class="text-right">Total</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{$total}}/-</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
```

i want to sum the all line total in total field without use of controller

Comment: Define the `$total` variable outside of the loop and it should work as you wish.

Comment: please check the file again

Comment: Yes, move the `$total` creation (`$total = 0;`) to outside the `@foreach` loop. Now you will set it to 0 on each iteration.

Comment: The `$total` needs to be before `@foreach($qInvoice as $sInvoice)`

Comment: An alternative, if `$qInvoice` is a collection is to use the `sum` api, see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-sum

Comment: ok. done. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Don't make the sum in the view, do it in the controller, for example:

```
$qInvoice->transform(function($sInvoice) {
    $sInvoice->line_total = $sInvoice->qty * $sInvoice->price; 
    return $sInvoice;
});

$total = $qInvoice->sum($line_total);
```

And return the view with $total and $qInvoice!